# Are végétalisme and véganisme different?

Tags: sens

Do the words végétalisme and véganisme have different meanings or are they synonyms?

Answer (score 4):

There's the same difference between *végétalisme* and *végétanisme* as between   "vegan nutrition" and  "veganism" in English. The former is abstaining from eating animal products and the latter is  abstaining from the use of animal products in your way of life (diet, clothes, etc).

Note that *France Terme* (the terminology database of the *Délégation générale à la langue française et aux langues de France*) recommends not to use the word *véganisme* but *végétalisme intégral* instead, that's why some dictionaries don't have an entry for *véganisme*,  but quite a lot of people use the word nevertheless.

***Végétalisme*** in the [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/v%C3%A9g%C3%A9talisme) :

> Principe diététique recommandant l'usage alimentaire des végétaux, à l'exclusion de la viande, du poisson et de tout produit d'origine animale.

***Végétalisme intégral*** in [France Terme](https://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/AGRI1295):

> **Définition**
> Mode de vie refusant l’utilisation des animaux au profit de l’homme et excluant en conséquence la consommation, directe ou sous forme de produits transformés, d’animaux et de produits d’origine animale.
> **Note**
> On trouve aussi le terme « véganisme », qui n’est pas recommandé.

You can also have the definitions in the GDT: [végétalisme](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8978116/vegetalisme), [végétalisme intégral](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/26529179/vegetalisme-integral).